# Landscape orientation switches to portrait

Tags: xcode, interface, orientation, landscape, autorotate

I'm new here, and I have a question. I've searched the web and found answers for my problem who seem to work for others. but not for me.

I'm building an iPad app (Xcode 4.3.3 using storyboards) in landscape view (right)
It launches in landscape-view but when i click a button (segue - Modal - Default) to jump to my next view the app jumps to portrait-view.

I've added this code and tried a lot of varieties (given on this website)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); }
```

-Set my view controllers to landscape mode instead of inferred.

-added initial interface orientation to my plist file.

But whatever I do, nothing seems to work properly.
What am I doing wrong?

I've uploaded my Xcode files to my server so you can check my code yourself.
[download zip.](http://bit.ly/OviqmC)

I hope you guys can help me out,
Thanks a bunch!

Mart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another class as `ViewControllerPushed` with the following method implemented:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); }
```

Then set it as the class of you pushed `ViewController` in **storyboard**.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked now!
I should create another class for each view I add?

Comment: @user1538733 Your are welcome. It's a solution. Usually you should. And many of them can share the same class you created.

Comment: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated in iOS 6.